# trying to debug old 1979 Micropolis 1016-2 floppy controller issue

Tags: floppy-drive, repair, s-100

I have an old IMSAI PCS-80/30 S-100.  It runs Micropolis MDOS 4.0.
I have Micropolis 1016-2 single drive (doesn't seem to read or write), Micropolis 1043-2 dual drive (reads sometimes when the moon is in the right phase)...many TEAC-55 drives.
The TEAC 55GFRs stopped working with the Micropolis controller card.  The TEAC-55FV seems to be working OK for read/Write/initialize operations.   Everything ran fine for 40 years until COVID19 and I spent time in the hospital, then the floppies started their non-operation problems.  Right now I boot from a 32K EPROM card so I can boot and then run the MDOS with the 1 TEAC 55FV only when unknown conditions are correct (the right room temperature, moon in phase and planet alignment).  I have 3 back up floppy controller cards, and none of those work.  It think with age the signal filtering has shifted with aging.  Questions... if I send 2MHz, 1MHz, 500KHz and 250KHz into the floppy controller card signal "RDA"... I figure R27, R46 and R40 need re-tuning.  Should RDATA look like a square wave 55Hex if setting are correct?   Do A14 74LS221 make a time window type filter that need to be calibrated to a 1uS and 2uS delays?  I don't have the service technician software package to be able to use the documented service procedure and utilities.  Disk RPM and Sector pulsing are correct. Best Regards greg